# StreamWriter no escribe el .csv

Tags: c#

estoy haciendo un programa que pasa datos de un .txt a un .csv, el tema es que nada de lo que hago se escribe en el .csv, tengo este codigo:

```
public void escribirCSV()
        {
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(cfg.pathProcesado(),true);
            string[] datosLinea;
            string[] lineas = Leer();
            foreach(string linea in lineas)
            {
                if (linea.Length != 0)//para que no se salga de indice
                {
                    datosLinea = linea.Split(';');
                    sw.Write(datosLinea[1]+";");
                }
              
            }
        }
public string[] Leer()
        {                  
            return File.ReadAllLines(cfg.pathMensajeros());
        }
```

El cfg.pathProcesado() solo es un método de una clase configuración que te da la ubicación del .csv, pero ya probé poner manualmente la ubicación del .csv para ver si era eso y nada. Ya trabajé con .csv antes, pero esto nunca me pasó. También probé dejar que el .csv lo creara el mismo StreamWriter por si se trata de un problema de permisos, pero nada. Por ultimo intente hacer lo siguiente:

```
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(cfg.pathProcesado(),true);
sw.Write("Hola");
```

Pero nada tampoco. En caso de que necesiten otra info la subo, supongo que con esto alcanza. Pd, también probé poner el .csv en el escritorio para probar en otra carpeta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Le falta activar el volcado inmediato del contenido del **StreamWriter**. Coloque lo  siguiente después del instanciamiento de **sw**

```
sw.AutoFlush = true;
```

y cerrar el **StreamWriter**. Coloque lo siguiente después del for

```
sw.Close();
```

Comment: Pues la solución me sirvió, pero quería saber porque ahora necesito hacer esto, si recién abrí otros de mis proyectos para re usar código y en esos programas funciona bien sin el AutoFlush

Comment: Imagino que no le escribía en el archivo porque estaba ejecutando el aplicativo en modo de depuración paso por paso. Lo que sucede es que la clase StreamWriter se inctancia por defecto con AutoFlush=false. Esto hace que lo que se va escribiendo no se vuelca de inmediato en el archivo, entonces cuando se esta depurando da la impresión de que no escribe en el archivo.